# How to map pitch and heading values from a Google StreetViewPov to (x,y) coordinates on full panoramic images

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-street-view, google-maps-api-3

We are trying to map pitch and heading values from a Google StreetViewPov to (x, y) coordinates on full panoramic images but none of the conversion methods we have tried work perfectly.

## Context

This is a view rendered in a Google Street View [StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanorama). It’s defined by a pitch and heading and other data (field of view, zoom, etc.).

[image: A view rendered in Google Street View]

Google takes Street View pictures with a 360° camera and stores them as tiles that aggregate as a single panorama image like this:

[image: A full panoramic streetview image]

## Our goal and findings thus far

Our goal is simply to map a pitch and heading (as defined [in the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPov)) from one of these Street View frames to an (x, y) pixel coordinate on the full panorama image. Google must be doing this with their Street View API (they also undo the distortion of the panorama with some projection, but we’re less worried about that), but we can’t figure out how to do this with the metadata the API exposes. We tried treating the panorama as a simple grid with pitch/heading lines similar to latitude/longitude lines, like this:

[image: An annotated full panoramic streetview image with linear lat/long lines]

Where H is the photographer heading defined in the documentation above. This works well for most panoramas. However, in some cases, the heading/pitch lines are not straight. Instead, they look something like this:

[image: An annotated full panoramic streetview image with curved lat/long lines]

This seems to occur when working with panoramas that were taken on a hill, so we attribute this to differences in the pitch of the car and the pitch of the camera (given by [photographer pitch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanorama.getPhotographerPov)). Through experimentation, we have achieved close mappings by treating the pitch lines as sine curves (peaking at the horizontal center of the image) with an amplitude that’s proportional to the photographer's pitch. We treat the heading lines as orthogonal to the sine curves, so we use derivatives to get their directions at various points.

However, we can’t find a formula that works for all panoramas. For example, sometimes these curves peak to the left or right of the image center as shown below (here, our algorithm draws the mapping curve with a blue line–it’s a bit hard to see):

[image: Annotated full panoramic streetview image with our reverse engineered (x,y) mapping algorithm drawn on top]

We speculate this is due to the roll of the camera, a value we can’t find in the metadata from our searches.

## Question

Is there a function mapping pitch and heading to (x, y) coordinates that works for all GSV panoramas and only uses data available through the Street View API? If so, what is it?

*We are happy to share any code that comes out of this discussion, as our project is open source!*